# Error 0x80070585 when running Fastcgi with IIS 8 + Python 3.4 + Django 1.8 + Windows Server 2012

Tags: django, iis, python-3.4, fastcgi, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to set up IIS 8 with Django 1.8.3 using Fastcgi and Python 3.4. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXbfHtAvubc) with the following Environment Variables:

- *DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE* ->      value: *FirstSite.settings*
- *PYTHONPATH* ->                  value: *C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Django\FirstSite*
- *WSGI_HANDLER* ->                value: *django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()*

I changed the WSGI Handler value from django.core.handlers.wsgi.wsgihandler() to django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application() because the tutorial talks about a previous Django version.

I followed everything in the tutorial, and as I try to open the website on my IE browser in Windows Server 2012 R2 I get the following error:

Keep in mind 8003 is the port I configured as the tutorial showed.

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error    scriptProcessor
>   could not be found in  application configuration
>
> Most likely causes: •IIS received the request; however, an internal
>   error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of
>   this error depends on which module handles the request and what was
>   happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
>
> •IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or
>   application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set
>   incorrectly.
>
> •IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or
>   application.
>
> •The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
>
> •The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility
>   Feature is not installed.
>
> Things you can try:
>
> •Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct
>   and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
>
> •Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
>
> •Verify the permissions for the DLL.
>
> •Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a
>   managed handler.
>
> •Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status
>   code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed
>   requests, click here.
>
> Detailed Error Information:
>
> Module    FastCgiModule
>
> Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
>
> Handler    Django Handler
>
> Error Code    0x80070585
>
> Requested URL    http://127.0.0.1:8003/
>
> Physical Path    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Django\FirstSite
>
> Logon Method    Anonymous
>
> Logon User    Anonymous
>
> More Information: This error means that there was a problem while
>   processing the request. The request was received by the Web server,
>   but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error. 
>   View more information »
>
> Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles: •294807

Is there any way to fix this error? Are there any extra steps for Python 3.4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found my error. The Handler Mapping Executable argument was pointing to fastcgi.py instead of wfastcgi.py

Comment: Hello Deepend, I will have to wait 22 hours to accept my own answer. Thank you.